# How to implement "grep -lr" in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, bash

I have a large intEnum object with legacy error codes.

```
class ErrorCodes(IntEnum):
    ERROR_UNKNOWN = 1
    ERROR_PERMISSION_DENIED = 3201
    ... # over 9000
    ERROR_LEGACY_AS_FOOBAR = 10001
```

I can check them if they are depricated by doing "grep -lr <error_name>" and see which ones are not imported anywhere else.
But doing this for each error code takes a long time.
How can this be automated in Python? Is it possible to call "grep" for every error name in a script, or is there a better tool in the python standard library?
Im used python 3.10.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wrote a very simple script. But probably not very accurate. But it works well for my problem. Might be useful to someone

```
import os, sys
def parse_file_by_errors() -> dict[str, set]:


    # We map error names with empty sets, which will be filled with files, with imports
    ERROR_IMPORT_MAP = {key: set() for key in list(Errors.__members__)}

    root_dir = './src/'
    for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root_dir):
        for file in files:
            if file.endswith('.py'): 
                file_path = os.path.join(subdir, file)  # get file path
                with open(file_path, 'r') as f:  
                    python_text = f.read() 
                    for error_name in ERROR_IMPORT_MAP.keys():
                        if error_name in python_text:
                            ERROR_IMPORT_MAP[error_name].add(file_path)
    return ERROR_IMPORT_MAP
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple shell script.

```
sed -n 's/.*\(ERROR_[_A-Z0-9a-z]*\).*/\1/p' file.py |
grep -rlFf - path/to/errordir
```

Depending on your use case, you might want to postprocess the output to group by error name, for example. Your question doesn't reveal in any more detail what exactly you hope for the output to do.

The `sed` script assumes that you have one error per line, and that all of them start with `ERROR_`. The extracted errors are passed to `grep -Ff -` which reads the patterns from standard input, one per line, and searches for them all literally (so any regex special characters are simply matched literally; here, mainly, we do this to speed up the processing, though).